# Play Framework with IntelliJ, no option to create 'Java File'

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

I got the IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition, and tried creating Play Framework Project. But something is wrong.

1. Create New - Project - Java - Play[image] 2.x. Project gets created. When I want to create a new Java File, I right clicked on Package - New - (no option to create Java file) - File, Directory, Html File, Stylesheet, Javascript etc. No option to Create Java File is shown.

I know that a folder has to be marked as Sources by doing right click - Mark Directory as - Sources.
However when I do that, my other files report saying folder is not under the declared package name.
This is specific to Play framework.  Appreciate assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Project view, is the ´app´ folder marked in blue as in the image?

[image: A Play project created via IntelliJ]

Alternatively, create the project from the command line with ´activator new ´.  In IntelliJ, you can then select either the root folder or the `build.sbt` to open the project.

In both cases, `app` should be marked in blue, indicating it's a source directory.

It's also possible you tried to create the Java file while IntelliJ was still initializing the project - during this time, it's not possible to create source files of any type.

Comment: App is not marked with blue color. Alternatively, if I right click and mark folder as source, the packages and dependencies break since path gets altered.

Comment: What happens if you create a project from the command line? Which version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: If I create from command prompt and then import in IntelliJ, it does give an option to give java files. But then I notice too much of compile time for a simple change if I create project by importing. However, If i directly create project in IDEA, its very fast, so I want to stick with creating project within IDEA. Can you assist me root cause the problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce it, so - unfortunately - no.  Try tweeting jetbrains, they're pretty hot on support.